# Account button for sample_app doesn't work on heroku, but works on local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

Sample_app from Hartl's tutorial doesn't work properly online, but works on local server.

Problem is, when I click on account drop-down button, there isn't any action, just '#' symbol appears at the end of URL. I read somewhere that problem might be in `app/assets/javascript/application.js` file and order of this part of code:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I tried every recommended order but it still doesn't work. Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the tutorial, but have you precompiled your assets?

`rake assets:precompile`

This turns all your asset pipeline into stuff that a production server can use.

On heroku you may need to do that as `heroku run bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: I did it now, I run that command both on local(rake assets:precompile) and online (heroku rake assets:precompile). Now app doesn't work online at all. Now on local server account button doesn't work..  Is there any command to reverse this commands? I don't know what I messed up..

Comment: Locally you can remove precompiled assets from public directory in your app

Comment: Stanislav, can you please tell me which one should I remove? Is there any time stamp or something similar? I never did this before, so if you can help me.. :)

Comment: @AleksaR try `rake assets:clean` to remove precompiled assets. Perhaps you don't actually want the asset pipeline at all, in which case add `config.assets.enabled = false` to `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and here is what I did:

1. application.js file as follows:

   ```
   //= require jquery  
   //= require bootstrap  
   //= require jquery_ujs  
   //= require turbolinks  
   //= require_tree .
   ```
2. production.rb code as follows:

   ```
    Rails.application.configure do
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

      # Code is not reloaded between requests.
      config.cache_classes = true

      # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
      # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
      # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
      # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
      config.eager_load = true

      # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
      # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
      # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
      # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

      # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
      config.serve_static_assets = true #switched to true from false from advice on stackoverflow

      # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
      config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
      # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

      # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
      config.assets.compile = true #switched to true from false from advice on stackoverflow

      # Generate digests for assets URLs.
      config.assets.digest = true

      # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

      # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
      # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

      # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
      config.force_ssl = true #zzz: uncommented from rails tutorial

      # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
      config.log_level = :info

      # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
      # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

      # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
      # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

      # Use a different cache store in production.
      # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

      # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
      # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

      # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
      # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
      # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

      # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
      # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
      config.i18n.fallbacks = true

      # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
      config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

      # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
      # config.autoflush_log = false

      # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
      config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

      # Do not dump schema after migrations.
      config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
    end
   ```
3. Terminal commands:

   ```
   bundle exec rake assets:clean  
   bundle exec rake assets:precompile  
   bundle exec rake test  
   git add -A  
   git commit -m "finally fixing this dropdown menu"  
   git push  
   git push heroku
   ```